# submit jquery and settimeout does not work

Tags: jquery, ajax, submit, settimeout

I am trying to  submit a form using JQuery, and after submitting it, open a window using AJAX retrieving a value from php. But I want to delay this last action 2 seconds. So my initial code was:

```
$(function() {      
$('form').on('submit',function () {     
 getepi();

 function getepi() {

 $.ajax({
    url : 'getepisodio.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : "hh",
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function (result) {

      window.open("historiaepisodio.php?id_episodio="+result['ajax']);    


    },
    error : function () {
       alert("error");
        }

      });

      }   
    });
  })
```

This works well without any delay. So I have been trying to use setTimeout(), but it does not work. I have tried as follow:

```
  $(function() {

    $('form').on('submit',function () {

       setTimeout(function(){getepi();},2000);

       function getepi() {

 $.ajax({
    url : 'getepisodio.php',
    type : 'POST',
    data : "hh",
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function (result) {

      window.open("historiaepisodio.php?     id_episodio="+result['ajax']);    
       //window.close(); 

    },
    error : function () {
       alert("error");
    }

    });

     }   
   });
 })
```

Even a simple alert like this does not work for me (only submit data):

```
  $(function() {

    $('form').on('submit',function () {

        setTimeout(function(){alert('Hello');},2000);

   });

  }
```

Comment: Aren't you preventing default behaviour of `form` submit??? `$('form').on('submit',function (e) { e.preventDefault(); /.../});`

Comment: No. I need at least 2 seconds in order to update a Mysql database using the submit data. After that  I get a reference value from the php file using ajax to open a new window using the value obtained. But I cannot delay the opening window process

Comment: Sounds like a XY problem. Anyway, if you don't prevent the form to be submited, the form submit behaviour refresh/redirect the page, so... BTW, using `window.open()` inside a timeout callback would be blocked by browser's popup blocker on most modern browser

Comment: Even adding :       $('form').on('submit',function (e) {
                          e.preventDefault;
                           setTimeout(function(){getepi();},2000);

Comment: `e.preventDefault();` not `e.preventDefault`

Comment: Sorry it was a syntax error....now it makes the delay but cannot submit the data....

Comment: You mean the ajax request isn't send? Or the popup isn't open? Or the form isn't submited?

Comment: The form now isn't submitted...the window is opened with the delay,

Comment: So,  if you want to still submit the form on ajax success, you need to call  native DOM `submit()` method, with relevant context. Your code should be like here: http://jsfiddle.net/01955scy/  But like said, AFAIK, popup would be blocked in this case, at least on chrome for sure (still depending user preference though). And to avoid user to submit form multiple time at once: http://jsfiddle.net/01955scy/1/  **But** referring to `No. I need at least 2 seconds in order to update a Mysql database using the submit data` for me you are facing a XY problem

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: Thank you very much A.Wolff. Your code works fine. Now I understand the problem. Thanks again for your help